# AsyncTask get function not showing Progressbar

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am making an application which get all html code from a website then data is extracted as per my requirements.I want a progress dialog when it async is working in background to get Data and after showing data in list view progress bar should dismiss.I have searched many question and tutorials on google. Problem is that i cant use get function here because of this my dialog doesn't show. So after that i searched google another method that say i should use call back methods. But i want data from doInBackground method. How can i get data if i will not use get method.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> myArray;
ArrayList<Integer> myImageArray;
ProgressDialog progress;
String getData;

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

     progress.setMessage("Downloading Music :) ");
progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
     progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
     progress.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{

            String result= "";

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data!=-1){

                char current = (char)data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }

            getData = result;

            return result;

        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

            return "Failed!";

        }


    }

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String total= "";
    String newTotal = "";

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    myImageArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();

    try {

        String text = task.execute("https://www.earticleblog.com/").get();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"td-module-thumb\">(.*?)</div>");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        while(m.find()){


          total += m.group(1);


        }

        p = Pattern.compile("a href=\"(.*?)\">");

        m = p.matcher(total);

        while (m.find()){

            newTotal += m.group(1);

        }

        p = Pattern.compile("title=\"(.*?)http");

        m = p.matcher(newTotal);

        while (m.find()){

            myArray.add(m.group(1));
            myImageArray.add(R.drawable.tryit);

        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    ArrayAdapter  adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,myImageArray,myArray);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

}
```

Comment: Apply My Solution and then check

Comment: did you get solution yet or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you should show `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute` method, and hide in `onPostExecute().` Moreover, with `progress = new ProgressDialog(this);` you are only creating dialog, not showing. Try `ProgressDialog.show(...)` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).

And, one more tip - don't do so much in `onCreate` (especially don't make any loops) - your app will show with a delay.

Comment: Don't use AsyncTask this way. Use only execute(params), and everything after task.execute() move to onPostExecute(). You are trying now to download data in main thread, and then use it immediately. Just call execute on AsyncTask, and then onCreate should be ended. When AsyncTask finish, it will call onPostExecute, and use your result there.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about it. I am going to try this and will let you know

Comment: thanks bro it works after i put all my code in onPostMethod

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this way for showing progressdailog.

in onPreExecute() you need to initialize the progress like this

```
progres = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progres.setMessage("Please Wait");
progres.show();
```

and in onPostExecute(); You need to dismiss the progress

```
if(progres.isShowing()){
progres.dismiss();
}
```

in Your Class just copy and replace this

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       progres = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       progres.setMessage("Please Wait");
       progres.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

           if(progres.isShowing()){
                progres.dismiss();
             }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{

            String result= "";

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data!=-1){

                char current = (char)data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }

            getData = result;

            return result;

        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

            return "Failed!";

        }


    }

}
```

Call your async task

```
task.execute();
```

or

```
new Downloadtask().execute();
```

try this way.

Comment: But when I do this progress dialog is still not showing

Comment: in your async class you can see there is no progressbar initialize and please take a look my updates answer @AnshumanKaushik

Comment: the problem is you are not calling async task so you need to call task like this task.execute(); @AnshumanKaushik

Answer (score 0):

you have to start progress bar in onPreExecute(); method and you have to close it in onPostExecute(); method

Comment: But when I do this progress dialog is still not showing

Answer (score 0):

Change your below two methods,

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "", "Please Wait");
    }
```

Comment: But when I do this progress dialog is still not showing

Comment: please apply my above solution. you just have to write one line in pre execute method, first check as you are able to see dialog or not then try to apply style and all, also remove progress = new ProgressDialog(this) line from onCreate method

Comment: Problem I am having is I m using get method because of it my dialog box is not showing I have to replace it with callback methods but don't know how to do it